# What are some good books for learning about typography?

Tags: typography, type

I really want to learn the basics of type. However, there are so many books on the subject that I get overwhelmed while searching.

Comment: Since you are polling the community to create a list of answers, I am converting this to community wiki.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two books I would recommend

1. [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063) by [Robert Bringhurst](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=ntt_athr_dp_sr_1?_encoding=UTF8&sort=relevancerank&search-alias=books&ie=UTF8&field-author=Robert%20Bringhurst). Simply a must read
2. [Grid Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3721201450) by [Josef Muller Brockman](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=ntt_athr_dp_sr_1?_encoding=UTF8&sort=relevancerank&search-alias=books&ie=UTF8&field-author=Josef%20Muller-Brockmann). Not typographically centered but really good at getting an understand about type in a broader context.

Comment: In addition to the implementation and usage of the typographic grid, _Grid Systems_ also covers quite a lot about the fundamentals of typography (e.g. margins, leading, kerning, paragraph spacing, folios, etc.). I would highly recommend it for new designers.

Answer (score 3):

This one is kind of old, but it's outstanding. To those desiring the basics it's a good fit:

[The Mac is not a Typewriter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201782634) by Robin Williams (link points to product page on Amazon).

There is an edition called "The PC is not..." also, but the classic work that many other people recommend is the Mac one.

Answer (score 1):

Meet Your Type by FontShop is a pretty decent quick and free guide to the basics, which explains a lot of common terms (like cap height, x height, counter, points, families, kerning, leading, etc.), how to choose the right font and make it work and so on. It's only a [52 page PDF](http://www.fontshop.com/education/) with lots of graphics, so if you really want to get into typography and learn about it, it's probably not a good choice. But for a quick introduction if you just want to get familiar with the basics, it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Thinking with type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568989695) is an excellent introduction and is the most
   modern.
2. [Designing with type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823014134) is a nice complement to it and a good
   reference as well.

They're always nearby on my shelf.

Answer (score 0):

This one is about typography in books, but the knowledge can be applied to screens as well: [The Form of the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881791164) by [Jan Tschichold](http://www.amazon.com/Jan-Tschichold/e/B000AQW30Y/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_4?qid=1321387835&sr=1-4).

Read the readers comments for more details. The introduction is from Bringhurst, whose book in essential too because it covers so much.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list, Stop Stealing Sheep and Find out How Type Works is also a great read. 
[http://www.amazon.com/Stop-Stealing-Sheep-Find-Works/dp/0672485435](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672485435)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some free books about typography

1. http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/fsfinalbook_single.pdf
2. http://unitinteractive.com/blog/2008/06/26/better-css-font-stacks/
3. http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/typographers_glossary.pdf
4. http://webtypography.net/
5. http://justcreativedesign.com/featured-articles/type-classification-ebook/
6. http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/type_selection.pdf
7. http://www.vignelli.com/canon.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few that I have in my collection that have some good information.

- The Elements of Typographic Style
- The TeXbook
- While You're Reading
- Idea Index: Graphic Effects and Typographic Treatments
- Exploring Typography
- Thinking with Type, 2nd revised and expanded edition: A Critical
  Guide for Designers, Writers, Editors, & Students

You can find all of these on Amazon or at B&N
Hope this helps and good luck

Answer (score 0):

I found [The Complete Manual of Typography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321127307) does an excellent job of unpacking complex knowledge in an elegant manner. (Link to Amazon)

Answer (score 0):

Introductory reading:

[Robin Williams: The Non-Designer's Design Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321534042)

It shows step by step how to apply simple principles (contrast, alignment, repetition, proximity) and use color/fonts to get a clear design for a business card, for example.